# Export/Import sequence in DB2

Tags: import, db2, export, sequence

I need to export a sequence to IXF file and then need to import it so that my sequence starts from same next value.

One way I can do is I can store the next value of sequence during export and then use it to alter the sequence while import.

Can we have a better solution for exporting and importing sequences.

Comment: What do you mean by "exporting a sequence to IXF file"? Is that the DDL for recreating the sequence? Or exporting a table including schema and IDENTITY column?

Comment: yes, I want to recreate the sequence that should start with current sequence value instead from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `CREATE` or `CREATE_REPLACE` option of `IMPORT` do note that this has been deprecated since at least DB2 9.7 https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dm.doc/doc/r0004690.html
so it is unlikely that the file format would be extended to include current sequence value information.

Still you could raise a RFE (or vote for one if one already exists) https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/

In the meantime, `db2look` will generate `ALTER SEQUENCE .. RESTART WITH ..` statements for you

Comment: I tried db2look with -d, -e, -z, -o. but it did not work. And I only want the DDL of sequence that should restart from the most recent next value.

Comment: what version of db2 are you using? It works for me `db2look -e -d $DATABASE -nofed -z paul | grep "RESTART WITH"` gives 
`ALTER SEQUENCE "PAUL    "."SEQ" RESTART WITH 21;
ALTER TABLE "PAUL    "."DDL" ALTER COLUMN "LINE_NO" RESTART WITH 8401;
ALTER TABLE "PAUL    "."IDENT" ALTER COLUMN "I" RESTART WITH 21;
`

Comment: I am using db2 version 10. Getting Error Message =
SQL0031C  File "U:\DB2LKFUN.BND" could not be opened. My user is already db2 admin.

Comment: Try explicitly binding that package http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21693517